# How to Disable/Enable Windows Firewall Rule based on associated port number

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall

I am trying to create a PowerShell script (Target Level OS 2008 R2) that 1.

1. Runs through a array of ports
2. List all firewall policy associated with the ports
3. Capture the "Rule Names" into a array *currently stuck here*
4. Run through each "Rule Name", either disable or enable the policy based on current state.

I am stuck at point 3 of my list above. Is anyone able to help or possibly direct me in the correct direction?

Current Code:

```
$array = @("3050", "300", "8080","7080","5090")
for ($i=0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++) {
    $searchPort = "(LocalPort.*" + $array[$i] + ")"
    $front = netsh advfirewall firewall show rule dir=in name=all |
             Select-String -Pattern ($searchPort) -Context 9,4
    Write-Host $front
}
```

Copy of result based on my current script:

```
Rule Name:                            interbase port
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled:                              Yes
Direction:                            In
Profiles:                             Domain,Private,Public
Grouping:
LocalIP:                              Any
RemoteIP:                             Any
Protocol:                             TCP
LocalPort:                            3050
RemotePort:                           Any
Edge traversal:                       No
Action:                               Allow

Rule Name:                            MT
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled:                              Yes
Direction:                            In
Profiles:                             Domain,Private,Public
Grouping:
LocalIP:                              Any
RemoteIP:                             Any
Protocol:                             UDP
LocalPort:                            300
RemotePort:                           Any
Edge traversal:                       No
Action:                               Allow

Rule Name:                            medtech port
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled:                              Yes
Direction:                            In
Profiles:                             Domain,Private,Public
Grouping:
LocalIP:                              Any
RemoteIP:                             Any
Protocol:                             UDP
LocalPort:                            300
RemotePort:                           Any
Edge traversal:                       No
Action:                               Allow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply extract the rule name from the pre-context of your match. Since you probably want to work with several elements from the pre- and post-context I'd recommend piping the output of `Select-String` into `ForEach-Object` instead of collecting it in a variable. Then you can toggle firewall rules e.g. like this:

```
$toggle = @{
  'yes' = 'no'
  'no'  = 'yes'
}

netsh ... | Select-String -Pattern $searchPort -Context 9,4 | ForEach-Object {
  $rule    = $_.Context.PreContext[0] -replace 'rule name:\s*'
  $enabled = $_.Context.PreContext[2] -replace 'enabled:\s*'

  & netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="$rule" new enable=$($toggle[$enabled])
}
```

Comment: Yes = No and No = Yes 

Comment: Thank you so much exactly what I needed! If ever in QT, NZ I owe you a beer!

Comment: Hi, 

Just a added quick note I found that the Toggle did not pass-through into "enable" therefore I did a new variable which went like this:


  netsh ... | Select-String -Pattern $searchPort -Context 9,4 | ForEach-Object {
   $rule    = $_.Context.PreContext[0] -replace 'rule name:\s*'
   $enabled = $_.Context.PreContext[2] -replace 'enabled:\s*'
  $newstatus=$toggle[$enabled]
   & netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="$rule" new enable="$newstatus"
  }


Thanks again

Comment: Ah, sorry about that (didn't test this detail before posting last night). It has to do with how PowerShell expands variables. You can either use an additional variable (like you have) or a subexpression (if you want to keep it "inline"). I updated my answer accordingly.